# RevMob/Revmob.h file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, revmob

I am adding Revmob ads to a persons Xcode project and everything is working for me and the app is compiling. However when I send it to him he gets this error:

`RevMob/Revmob.h file not found`

Why is this happening???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely a problem with user header search path setting in the build settings of the project. Check it and if there is a full path, make sure to change it to relative (by manually rewriting it). Or if it is a framework, then change the framework search paths. See the screenshot for more info.

[image]